# php email image not display in gmail

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, pyrocms

I want to display image in email that send from php. In yahoo the image was display but in gmail the image is missing.

This is the code for display image

```
 <a href="{{ url:site }}user/active/{{ id }}/{{ code }}"><img alt="" data-pyroimage="true" src="{{ url:site }}image/sample.png" style="width:66%;" /></a>
```

This is the image url after i inspect in gmail

```
<a href="http://ipaddress/user/active/123456/123cp00a42c9b78514000c53f8294e5ec0d0aasgd" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://ipaddress/users/activate/123456/123cp00a42c9b78514000c53f8294e5ec0d0aasgd&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1233456567575&amp;usg=AFQjCNGTV3UZZ4wSgFSsx_rcn7-mh3UUxw"><img alt="" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/KaJG60d7WUoIwstJlDYAp8vLq1SSpmWyOZlrgZtUJMtHoBCEr863637_4tdJaibPlgJy7jnzXHs5RGv8C3g=s0-d-e1-ft#http://ipaddress/image/sample.png" style="width:66%" class="CToWUd"></a>
```

Comment: Did you check if there was a note in Gmail saying: "Display images from this email"? By default, images are not shown especially if it's from a not trusted source

Comment: yeah i check then i click "display image" and still not showing image @h

Comment: do an inspect element inside the mail and check the path of your image if it's correct

Comment: this the path <a href="http://ipaddress/user/active/123456/123cp00a42c9b78514000c53f8294e5ec0d0aasgd" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://ipaddress/users/activate/123456/123cp00a42c9b78514000c53f8294e5ec0d0aasgd&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1233456567575&amp;usg=AFQjCNGTV3UZZ4wSgFSsx_rcn7-mh3UUxw"><img alt="" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/KaJG60d7WUoIwstJlDYAp8vLq1SSpmWyOZlrgZtUJMtHoBCEr863637_4tdJaibPlgJy7jnzXHs5RGv8C3g=s0-d-e1-ft#http://ipaddress/image/sample.png" style="width:66%" class="CToWUd"></a>
Is it because of proxy

Comment: Paste that into your question. It's unreadable in the comment

Comment: already state in question

Comment: did you check if the image source given points to your image?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `img` plugin function to reveal a physical file location. If that's an image in the public directory something like this might work:

```
{{ img('public::image/sample.png').url }}
```

Then you can bet that Google will treat it much like a native image source.